# valuechangelistener does not populate values in text box

Tags: jsf, valuechangelistener

Here is my jsp:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{member.dependentName}" onchange="this.form.submit()"
immediate="true" valueChangeListener="#{member.getDependentAddress}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{member.dependentList}" />
 </h:selectOneMenu> 
   <h:inputText value="#{member.personName}" immediate="true" />
   <h:inputText value="#{member.dob}" immediate="true" />
```

And this, the function valuechangelistener fires.

```
 public void getDependentAddress(ValueChangeEvent e) {  
    setPersonName((getDependentsList().get(e.getNewValue().toString())
            .getDependentName()));
    setDob(getDependentsList().get(e.getNewValue().toString()).getBirth());
    System.out.println("New dob value : " + dob);
    System.out.println("New name value : " + personName);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}
```

The two sysouts give the new value in the console but once the page loads, the fields are blank. I have tried all scopes for the bean. No go. What am i missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed nothing. You've just something too much. To get it to work, you should *remove* `immediate="true"` from the to-be-changed components.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{member.dependentName}" onchange="this.form.submit()"
   immediate="true" valueChangeListener="#{member.getDependentAddress}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{member.dependentList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu> 
<h:inputText value="#{member.personName}" />
<h:inputText value="#{member.dob}" />
```

The `immediate="true"` on an `UIInput` component will cause its validations phase to take place in apply request values phase instead. This gives you the opportunity to use `FacesContext#responseComplete()` inside a `valueChangeListener` method skip other components which doesn't have `immediate="true"` set from being processed. As you have now, with `immediate="true"`, they are *also* processed.

---

Please note that this is essentially a hack from the old JSF 1.x ages. If you're already using JSF 2.x, you should be using `<f:ajax listener>` instead.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{member.dependentName}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{member.dependentList}" />
   <f:ajax listener="#{member.getDependentAddress}" render="name dob" />
</h:selectOneMenu> 
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{member.personName}" />
<h:inputText id="dob" value="#{member.dob}" />
```

with

```
public void getDependentAddress() {
    Dependent dependent = getDependentsList().get(dependentName); // Isn't that actually a Map instead of List?
    personName = dependent.getDependentName();
    dob = dependent.getBirth();
}
```

Comment: It works! All my googling on valuechangelistener lead to your blog. Awesome blog. Thank you. Note: The application is going to run on an old server, so I've to stick to JSF 1.X.